# Iterating with two iterators

Tags: java, iterator

I have two array lists which have a different number of items in them.
The first iteration works well, but when it moves on the the next, nothing happens which I suspect is because the second iterator has no next. Is there anyway to reset it?

```
Iterator<Integer> itID = ID.iterator();
    Iterator<String> itTable = Table.iterator();
    Iterator<String> itColumn = Column.iterator();
    while(itID.hasNext()){
        int i = itID.next();
        System.out.println(i);
        while(itTable.hasNext()){
            String SQL = "select " + itColumn.next() + " from " +  itTable.next() + " where id=" + i;
            System.out.println(SQL);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does this `Column` thing come from? Is it in any way dependent on `Table`?

Comment: @DirkLachowski The Column is a list which is the same size as the table list

Comment: seems strange to iterate through 2 iterators simultaneously. Has a future bug written all over it. An `Iterator<Pair<String, String>>` or some class containing 2 strings to capture the point of these Strings better would make more sense I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have to move inside the first cycle the instantiation of the iterators `itTable` and `itColumn`.

```
Iterator<Integer> itID = ID.iterator();
while (itID.hasNext()) {
    // Every time you ask for an iterator, you obtain a new one.
    Iterator<String> itTable = Table.iterator();
    Iterator<String> itColumn = Column.iterator();
    int i = itID.next();
    System.out.println(i);
    while(itTable.hasNext()){
        String SQL = "select " + itColumn.next() + " from " +  itTable.next() + " where id=" + i;
        System.out.println(SQL);
    }
}
```

So the best way to "reset" an iterator is to ask to the aggregate for a new instance of the iterator itself.

Answer (score 0):

The iterators used in the nested loop should be initialized inside of the first loop so they get reset every time the outer loop iterates.

But you can (and should) just use a for loop to iterate through an `ArrayList`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    // use myList.get(i)
}
```

Or just

```
for (String s : myList) { // Change string to whatever type your list is holding
    // use 's'
}
```

The second loop there is called a `for each` loop. It is designed for iterating through lists and arrays. For your purpose this one will not work because you're iterating through 2 lists, but I thought I'd bring it up anyway. You should use the first for loop.

Comment: it is not possible to use the **foreach** construct in its example.

Comment: The latter is much better than the former, and is implemented using iterators. The former is bad form and shouldn't be used. Better off to leave the job of implementation of iteration to the list itself. Because if this was a linked list or some other list this could be a way slower way of iterating.

Comment: @Cruncher riccardo is right, a for each loop can't be used to iterate through 2 lists at once.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit past the scope of the question, but this is my thoughts. 
Iterating through two lists which you assume to be the same size, is asking for trouble. If these two values are supposed to be coupled together, then well.. couple them together. The following class can do that:

```
class SQLField 
{
    private String tableName;
    private String columnName;
    public SQLField(String tableName, String columnName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public getSelect() {
        return "select " + this.columnName + " from " + this.tableName
    }
}
```

This makes the using code:

```
Iterator<Integer> itID = ID.iterator();
while (itID.hasNext()) {
    // Every time you ask for an iterator, you obtain a new one.
    Iterator<SQLField> fields = SQLFields.iterator();
    int i = itID.next();
    System.out.println(i);
    for(SQLField field : fields) {
        String SQL = field.getSelect() + " where id = " + i;
        System.out.println(SQL);
    }
}
```

This is a much better approach in my opinion.